# Object Reference error when reading cookie from an external class

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a cookie with a users authentication data set via:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)));
```

Now, when I try read the cookie from another class using:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
myCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```

I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.
I've checked my browser cookie and the `.ASPXAUTH` cookie is there with data.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? I've tried with both `request` and `response`

**Edit:** `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get` returns the same error

**Edit2:** Seems as if `HttpContext.Current` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

.net 4.5 has some issues reading `HttpContext.Current`

[Reading this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072142/httpcontext-current-user-is-always-null#2072187), add the following to your `web.config`

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```